# New HDD - Not being detected

Tags: hard-drive

I dropped my Laptop a couple of feet, and as a result my HDD was screwed. I hurriedly ordered a new one, and connected it to my laptop. But it refuses to get detected, my laptop still says 'No HDD connected'.

Laptop: HP DV6 6121tx

Old HDD (640 gig): http://storage.toshiba.eu/cms/en/hdd/computing/product_detail.jsp?productid=340

New HDD (500gig) : http://www.hgst.com/hard-drives/mobile-drives/7mm-thin-and-light-drives/travelstar-z5k500

What could be going wrong? Have I bought an incompatible HDD in a hurry? Although I don't see anything such in the specs.

I have a SATA->USB casing, and I tried this HDD on another computer inside the casing, and Windows is able to detect it. So the HDD is fine...

Comment: did you checked HDD by connecting it to any other machine?

Comment: Was your HDD damaged or the connection to it?

Comment: In what way it is not detected? Is it not detectable in BIOS? Try changing AHCI mode to IDE?

Comment: Your replacement unit was a SATA I hdd but your old unit was SATA III.  While they are suppose to be compatibile to a certain degree this might not be true with your hardware.

Answer (score 0):

So you've tried "this" (the new?) HDD in the external case, and it worked.

If "this" is already the old one, then your laptop is broken and your HDD is fine.

If you have not already done so ("this" being a bit non-specific) try the original HDD in the external case - if it works, then the connection to the HDD in the laptop is what's broken. If not, then you fall back to potentially different compatibility issues, as mentioned in comments above.  Of course, you could have *both* a broken disk *and* a broken internal connection, but if you start the process by tracking down all the single points of failure, it helps.